# How to modify appearance of some equations

Tags: math-mode, arrows, braket

I am trying to make several codes for physics, but I think in the first equation is too small compared another equation. I need your advice for another code.

```
\begin{gather*} 
\bra{\psi_m}\times\xleftarrow{
i\hbar\sum_{n}\dot{C}(t)_ne^{-iE^{(0)}_nt/\hbar}\ket{\psi_n} =
\sum_{n}H_1C_n(t)e^{-iE^{(0)}_nt/\hbar}\ket{\psi_n}}\\
i\hbar\sum_{n}\dot{C}(t)_ne^{-iE^{(0)}_nt/\hbar}\delta_{m,n} =
\sum_{n}C_n(t)e^{-iE^{(0)}_nt/\hbar}\bra{\psi_m}H_1\ket{\psi_n}\\    
i\hbar\dot{C}(t)_m =
\sum_{n}C_n(t)e^{i(E^{(0)}_m-E^{(0)}_n)t/\hbar}\bra{\psi_m}H_1\ket{\psi_n} \\     
\boxed{\dot{C}(t)_m = -\frac{i}{\hbar}
\sum_{n}C_n(t)e^{i\omega_{mn}t}\bra{\psi_m}H_1\ket{\psi_n}}    
\end{gather*}
```

[image]

Comment: Add \displaystyle

Comment: It doesn't work with my code.

Comment: @Air.api add it here `\xleftarrow{\displaystyle ... }`. And for me as a reader it feels you should align the `=` signs

Comment: In addition to considering `\displaystyle` in the argument of `\xleftarrow`, do also consider using `\textstyle`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the meaning should be, but perhaps you want something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,braket}

\begin{document}

\[
\bra{\psi_m}\times
\underleftarrow{
  i\hbar\sum_{n}\dot{C}(t)_ne^{-iE^{(0)}_nt/\hbar}\ket{\psi_n} =
  \sum_{n}H_1C_n(t)e^{-iE^{(0)}_nt/\hbar}\ket{\psi_n}
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have the following suggestions:

- For the equation in the first row, consider placing the argument of `\xleftarrow` in text style; the default is script style, which indeed looks a bit, well, small. Going to display style, on the other hand, seems like too much of a good thing since there's no need to make the summation symbols really big.
- For the second and third row, consider replacing the `e^{...}` terms with `\exp(...)` expressions. Also, consider using the more compact `\braket` notation instead of having separate `\bra` and `\ket` terms.
- For the fourth row, the only thing you may want to change is using the more compact `\braket` notation instead of providing `\bra` and `\ket` terms.

The following screenshot shows various before-and-after combinations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,braket}
\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\bra{\psi_m}\times\xleftarrow{% default style for argument is script style
i\hbar\sum_{n}\dot{C}(t)_ne^{-iE^{(0)}_nt/\hbar}\ket{\psi_n} =
\sum_{n}H_1C_n(t)e^{-iE^{(0)}_nt/\hbar}\ket{\psi_n}}\\
\shortintertext{versus}
\bra{\psi_m}\times\xleftarrow{\textstyle
i\hbar\sum_{n}\dot{C}(t)_ne^{-iE^{(0)}_nt/\hbar}\ket{\psi_n} =
\sum_{n}H_1C_n(t)e^{-iE^{(0)}_nt/\hbar}\ket{\psi_n}}\\
\shortintertext{or}
\bra{\psi_m}\times\xleftarrow{\displaystyle
i\hbar\sum\nolimits_{n}\dot{C}(t)_ne^{-iE^{(0)}_nt/\hbar}\ket{\psi_n} 
    \sum\nolimits_{n}H_1C_n(t)e^{-iE^{(0)}_nt/\hbar}\ket{\psi_n}}
\end{gather*}
\hrule
\begin{gather*}
i\hbar\sum_{n}\dot{C}(t)_ne^{-iE^{(0)}_nt/\hbar}\delta_{m,n} =
\sum_{n}C_n(t)e^{-iE^{(0)}_nt/\hbar}\bra{\psi_m}H_1\ket{\psi_n}\\
i\hbar\dot{C}(t)_m =
\sum_{n} C_n(t)e^{i(E^{(0)}_m -E^{(0)}_n)t/\hbar} \bra{\psi_m}H_1\ket{\psi_n}\\
\intertext{versus}
i\hbar\sum_{n}\dot{C}(t)_n\exp(-iE^{(0)}_nt/\hbar)\delta_{m,n} 
= \sum_{n}C_n(t)\exp(-iE^{(0)}_nt/\hbar) \braket{\psi_m|H_1|\psi_n}\\
i\hbar\dot{C}(t)_m 
= \sum_{n} C_n(t)\exp\bigl(i(E^{(0)}_m -E^{(0)}_n)t/\hbar\bigr) \braket{\psi_m|H_1|\psi_n}
\end{gather*}
\hrule
\begin{gather*}
\boxed{\dot{C}(t)_m = -\frac{i}{\hbar} \sum_{n} C_n(t)e^{i\omega_{mn}t}
    \bra{\psi_m}H_1\ket{\psi_n}}\\
\shortintertext{versus}
\boxed{\dot{C}(t)_m = -\frac{i}{\hbar} \sum_{n} C_n(t)e^{i\omega_{mn}t}
    \braket{\psi_m|H_1|\psi_n}}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks @Mico for your suggestion. It's good advice for me.